# how to save CoreDocument in Stanford nlp to disk

Tags: java, save, stanford-nlp

After creating anotated CoreDocument want to save it to disk and later retrieve it.

Computing an anotated CoreDocument is slow.  After created it once want to use it later, i.e. retrieve it from disk.

```
props.setProperty("annotators", 
"tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,depparse,coref,kbp,quote");
    // set a property for an annotator, in this case the coref annotator is being set to use the neural algorithm
    props.setProperty("coref.algorithm", "neural");
    // build pipeline
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    // create a document object
    CoreDocument document = new CoreDocument(content);
    // annnotate the document
    pipeline.annotate(document);
```

Comment: Look into Java object serialization: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the AnnotationSerializer class:

https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/AnnotationSerializer.html

Specifically, while there are several instantiations of this class, we have mainly used the `ProtobufAnnotationSerializer`.

You can see examples of use in some of the integration tests. `ProtobufSerializationSanityITest` is a simple example of how to use it. `ProtobufAnnotationSerializerSlowITest` is a much more thorough but complicated example. You can find them in the [Github repository](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP).

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks for the help, as I'm new to the stanford npl. The AnnotationSerialize class 
moved me forward in saving the document to disk. I had a further misunderstanding 
about interpreting the result.  I didn't realize that the result (pair.first) 
contained the full result.  The pertinent code is:

public void writeDoc(CoreDocument document, String filename ) {
    AnnotationSerializer serializer = new ProtobufAnnotationSerializer();
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        OutputStream ks = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        ks = serializer.writeCoreDocument(document, ks);
        ks.flush();
        ks.close();
    }catch(IOException ioex) {
        logger.error("IOException "+ioex);
    }
  }

public void ReadSavedDoc(String filename) {
    try {
        File initialFile = new File(filename);
        InputStream ks = new FileInputStream(initialFile);

     // Read
        AnnotationSerializer serializer = new ProtobufAnnotationSerializer();
        InputStream kis = new ByteArrayInputStream(ks.readAllBytes());
        Pair<Annotation, InputStream> pair = serializer.read(kis);
        pair.second.close();
        Annotation readAnnotation = pair.first;
        kis.close();
     //Output
        List<CoreLabel> newTokens = 
readAnnotation.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class);
        for(CoreLabel atoken: newTokens)
            System.out.println("atoken "+atoken);
        List<CoreMap> newSentences = 
readAnnotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
        logger.info("Sentences "+newSentences);
        String newEntity = 
readAnnotation.get(CoreAnnotations.NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class);
        System.out.println("named entity "+newEntity);
        String newPOS = 
readAnnotation.get(CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class);
        logger.info("pos "+newPOS);
        for(CoreMap sentence : newSentences){
            System.out.println(sentence);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  catch (ClassCastException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Exception: "+ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
Hope this helps someone else.  Don
```